# How to properly deploy angular application (based on ngBoilerplate and using nginx)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, deployment, ngboilerplate

I have found, that [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) was extremly easy for making first steps in webdevelopment based on angular. Right know I am trying to prepare my deployment pipeline, so I use github, travis-ci and dockerized nginx image.

I thought that to properly deploy my simple angular website I just have to:

```
git clone https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp.git
cd ngbp/
npm install
bower install
grunt compile
```

and then copy `bin/` directory:

```
bin/
├── assets
│   ├── ngbp-0.3.2.css
│   ├── ngbp-0.3.2.js
│   └── README.md
└── index.html
```

to nginx directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

Unfortunately, something is wrong with javascript code. I got error

```
Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ngBoilerplate.home

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That seems about right, of the top of my head. If you open the developer console, do you see any network errors? Can you confirm the contents of the scripts in the network tab?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller: please take a look on my short screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjBcKT2tgAk

Comment: The `compile` task assumes you've already run the `build` task. Just run `grunt` instead. https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp#build-vs-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ngbp, Grunt tasks are broken into [two categories](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp#build-vs-compile): build and compile. The build task does everything needed to *run* the site, particularly while developing, and the compile task concatenates and minifies files for production.

Your problem here is that you aren't running the build task, which the compile task needs in order to operate. To save time (see above link), these are separate. If you want to go from start to finish, including minification, just run `grunt`, which is equivalent to running `grunt build compile`.

The README assumes that you do all your development with `grunt build` and `grunt watch`, after which you can simply run `grunt compile` before you deploy.